# What is the correct way to make django model saving trickle down?

Tags: python, django

say I have these models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Badge (models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

I want to save a new person along with his badges, and i get a POST request containing both the person details and the badges he possesses. I can't seem to find a way of creating all the objects than saving them with only one statement. I can save everything separately and then link the objects together but it gets complex as things become more inter-connected.

What is the best method of doing such?

Cheers,
Gil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems fairly easy in this case, first the Person and after the Badge?

If you're looking for a batch adding feature, try the [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method.

So in your case:

```
person = Person(first_name='Guido', last_name='van Rossum')
Badge.objects.bulk_create([
    Badge(owner=person),
    Badge(owner=person),
    Badge(owner=person),
    Badge(owner=person),
])
```

Comment: This case is just an example. My case involves more connectivity between models.But after I do as you say, when i approach to save the objects: If I just save the object the saves won't trickle down (think about what if the badge owner was a foerign key of a third model that needs saving)

Comment: That's true, you have to take care of it yourself.